# Mysql Order By Json Count

Tags: mysql

I try that code;

```
select * 
from `diary` 
where date(`created_at`) = 2022-05-10 
order by JSON_LENGTH(like) asc limit 1
```

Like column in my table;

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------+
| id | like         | created_at              |
+----+--------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | ['asas']     | 2022-05-10 07:02:42     |
+----+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Here is my error; `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'like) asc limit 1' at line 1`

If I don't use order by, code work fine. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`like` is a reserved word. I solved the problem by quoting the column name using backticks (`` ` ``), like this:

```
select * from `diary` 
where date(`created_at`) = 2022-05-10 
order by JSON_LENGTH(`like`) asc limit 1
```